# Mental Excercises

Tags: reference-request

I just solved Einstein's fish riddle. I found it sufficiently entertaining. I was hoping to get recommendations to a site that offers questions that are just as challenging or more. You can also post such questions as answers here. (Such questions need not be mathematical(like Einstein's own riddle. I merely request that they be sufficiently mentally stimulating. Something I can be doing regularly as a pastime))

I asked this here, because I don't know the right SE site for this, and because Einstein's fish riddle can be treated as a Math problem(A set theoretic approach to solving it may be useful).

Comment: Are you looking for math riddles or general challenging puzzles?

Comment: Both actually. Just a pastime, and something to sharpen my brain. If it improves my Mathematical reasoning skills then why not?

Comment: You're looking for Puzzles SE as Mitch's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One that I really enjoy is one that I found on xkcd called "[Blue Eyes](https://xkcd.com/blue_eyes.html)", it is self proclaimed "The Hardest Logic Puzzle in the World".

Might I refer you to [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). If you look under the tags there lots of mathematics puzzles that you can look at. Things such as combinatorics or mathematics, even calculation puzzles. But it's not limited only to that. I think you'll find it very rewarding. I might recommend starting with the [highest voted questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) first.